# Parallel GET to API which uses HATEOAS in C# (Blazor)

Tags: c#, http, blazor, hateoas

I´m using an API (which is not my own so I can´t change anything about it) which implements HATEOAS. The JSON files I receive with a GET look something like this:

```
{
"_links": {
    "_children": {
        "child1": {
            "href": "/document/child1"
        },
        "child2": {
            "href": "/document/child2"
        },

...
```

Which means, at first I call the root component, from which I get the links to all children, then I call the URL of each children to get their children and so on.

That´s not really efficient, because sometimes there are hundreds of children and one request takes around 250 ms. At the moment I use a recursive function which makes a call like this (Blazor WebAssembly):

```
response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(rootUrl + child.HRef);
```

I´m using the System.Net.Http.HttpClient. Now I thought I could make all these calls somehow parallel to save some time. I found some solutions, how to make parallel requests when you already know the URLs (like this one: http://www.michalbialecki.com/2018/04/19/how-to-send-many-requests-in-parallel-in-asp-net-core/) but no really good solution if you get your URLs after each call.

I thought of something like creating a thread for each child of the root component, then for each child of a child until the maximum of parallel calls is reached.

I´m not sure how to implement something like this and would be happy if someone has an answer.

Comment: `I thought of something like creating a thread for each child of the root component, then for each child of a child until the maximum of parallel calls is reached.` Creating threads is unnecessary. As shown in the link in your question.

Comment: If you want to use `Task.WhenAll` you need to collect all of these URLs first. You can't really make this recursive then.

Comment: @Konrad exactly this is my problem. If I get all the URLs at first I save no time to my current solution because the time to parse the JSON is really small compared to the time a HTTP request takes. I´m searching for a solution to make some of those request parallel so that it´s not that time consuming.

Comment: @devbf There's no other way if there are thousands or hundreds of children returned from 1 request. The only way is to collect these `href`s and use `Task.WhenAll`. That's how HATEOAS works, you usually end up with a lot of requests because responses return only urls. 250ms for 1 request seems weird though. How big is that data?

Comment: @Konrad maybe I was a little unclear, the first request returns a root component with its children. Then I make a new request for each child which in return delivers all of its children and so on. So I thought after I made the first request, I start for example 3 (if there are 3 children of the root component) requests which run parallel, get the next children and so on.

Comment: @devbf You can only use `Task.WhenAll`. Creating threads etc. won't help you here because these kind of operations are I/O bound. If you want to display these things somewhere without waiting for everything to complete you can use `yield return`. This seems more like the server hosting the API is having some problems. A lot will depend on your connection here.

Comment: @Konrad okay, thank you, have hoped there would maybe be a better solution.

Comment: I would do it that way: 1.Get root component. 2. Create list with request tasks for each child. 3. Use `Task.WhenAll` 4. Repeat

Comment: `If you want to use Task.WhenAll you need to collect all of these URLs first. You can't really make this recursive then.` No you don't need to collect **all** of them first - it takes an enumerable. You can `yield return` them as you find them.

Comment: Parallels call are not going to work on Blazor WASM at the moment, there isn't real multithreading on mono WASM. You're going to loss some responses. Doing that server side will work

Comment: @aguafrommars are there any plans to implement this feature in mono Wasm?

Comment: @devbf [This issue on github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5475) can be a response for modern browser. However, till we need JS interopt to make an http request, we gonna be limited by JS